# array push function not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays

```
let videoQry = "SELECT cp.*,ud.user_id,ud.firstname,ud.lastname,ud.displayname,ud.profile_pic,c.challenge_name from `challenge_post` as cp INNER JOIN `user_details` as ud ON cp.challenge_user_id = ud.user_id INNER JOIN `challenge` as c ON c.id = cp.challenge_id WHERE cp.status = '1' ";
    dbcon.db.query(videoQry, (err, videoQryRes) => {
        
        let array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < videoQryRes.length; i++) {
            let fetchComment = "SELECT pc.comment,pc.comment_created_date,ud.firstname,ud.lastname,ud.profile_pic FROM `post_comment` as pc INNER JOIN `user_details` as ud ON pc.user_id = ud.user_id WHERE `challenge_post_id` = '" + videoQryRes[i]['id'] + "' and pc.status = '1' ";
            dbcon.db.query(fetchComment, (err, fetchCommentRes) => {
                array.push(fetchCommentRes);
                
            });
            
        }
        res.json({ status: '1', result:videoQryRes, comment: array});
        
    });
```

what is wrong with this array push. i am getting blank array .but

fetchCommentRes has some data.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a callback:

```
dbcon.db.query(fetchComment, (err, fetchCommentRes) => { // <-- This is a CB
    array.push(fetchCommentRes);                
});
```

which works async, this means that when the last line is executed the array is still empty!

You can try to rewrite the code to use async/await and to wait for the results to arrive before sending the response back, this should look something like this:

```
async function fetchResults(dbcon , res) {
    const videoQry = "SELECT cp.*,ud.user_id,ud.firstname,ud.lastname,ud.displayname,ud.profile_pic,c.challenge_name from `challenge_post` as cp INNER JOIN `user_details` as ud ON cp.challenge_user_id = ud.user_id INNER JOIN `challenge` as c ON c.id = cp.challenge_id WHERE cp.status = '1' ";    
    const videoQryRes = await dbcon.db.query(videoQry);
        
    const array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < videoQryRes.length; i++) {
        const fetchComment = "SELECT pc.comment,pc.comment_created_date,ud.firstname,ud.lastname,ud.profile_pic FROM `post_comment` as pc INNER JOIN `user_details` as ud ON pc.user_id = ud.user_id WHERE `challenge_post_id` = '" + videoQryRes[i]['id'] + "' and pc.status = '1' ";
        const fetchCommentRes = await dbcon.db.query(fetchComment);
        array.push(fetchCommentRes);
        
    }
    return res.json({ status: '1', result: videoQryRes, comment: array });
}
```